# How to approach eliminating a record in my credit history that is hurting my score

Tags: credit-score, credit, credit-history

I have a record in my credit history that shows a delinquency from 4/2005 that was paid off but was also marked as a "charge off." As of January 2011, this record no longer shows up in my file for Equifax or Trans Union, but it is still being reported at Experian.

Is there any good way to ask the creditor or Experian to stop reporting the record?

Why is it only showing up at Experian at this point?

Is this at the discretion of the credit bureau or creditor?

Answer (score 7):

The period that the mark can stay on your credit history is

*... takes deep breath ...*

seven years, beginning 180 days from the month and year of the commencement of the delinquency that immediately preceded the charge-off, as reported by the financial institution making the claim.

So, it may be that you haven't run through this seven years yet.  Don't know why it's not on the other two.

More information [here](http://www.creditinfocenter.com/creditreports/cr_time.shtml).

Answer (score 4):

If it is an error you should dispute it with the Experian.  Send a certified letter.  That gives them 30 days to respond, either by removing it or contacting the creditor and validating the debt.  If the creditor says that it was a charge off you must take it to them.

See:
http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/edu/pubs/consumer/credit/cre21.shtm

By the way if the report is correct, sorry, you can't remove items just because you don't like how it affects your score.  Wait it out.