# How long will defect remain in credit history?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-history

I have read [this question/answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6239/how-to-approach-eliminating-a-record-in-my-credit-history-that-is-hurting-my-sco) that suggests that it takes 7 years for items to clear from a credit file.

Is this the same in the UK? And in the meantime, if I have late payments showing on my report, what can be done to mitigate the effects of this on my credit ratings?

Suppose I have credit card abc for 2 years, with a brilliant credit history and no late payments; And credit card xyz from 3 years ago with a few late payments, (the account is now closed), will this still affect my ratings? Even though I have been responsible with the new credit card for 2 years?

Comment: I would call one of the rating agencies. Not that they have an universal policy, but you might get an idea. I see credit cards on my account on equifax for the past 5 years. Not sure about experian.